# New DB entry not being assigned Id ASP.Net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

So I am building my project off the ASP.NET identity template that was made with my solution. I have the below models that make up my DB but when I try making a new Session it is not being assigned an Id.

```
public class Client
{
    public Client()
    {
        Session = new HashSet<Session>();
    }
    [Key, ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Session> Session { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
public class Session
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual Measurements Meansurements { get; set; }
    public virtual MeasurementsExtended MeasurementsExtended { get; set; }
}
public class Measurements
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Session")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Session Session { get; set; }
}
public class MeasurementsExtended
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Session")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Session Session { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATED** Controller

```
var session = new Session { Client = db.Client.Find(model.SelectedClient),};
var measurements = new Measurements { Session = session};
var measurementsExtended = new MeasurementsExtended { Session = session};
ession.Meansurements = measurements;
session.MeasurementsExtended = measurementsExtended;
db.Session.Add(session);
```

Do I explicitly need to assign an Id? I have not done that for any other custom models and they are assigned an Id without a problem
I am still new to MVC to feel free to let me know if there's something else I might be doing wrong

**Update**
So after Discussion I have fixed the Database generating Id's but now Im getting the error `InnerException {"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'project.dbo.Sessions'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}`
Yet as im looking at the object in he debugger it deffinately has the Id of 0, I even tried manually setting it to 1 with no change.
**Update 2 - Working**
Model

```
public class Session
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    ...
```

Controller

```
var session = new Session { Id = Guid.NewGuid() ...
```

Comment: you can mark the `Id` in Session.cs with [Key]

Comment: @kienct89 I just tried doing that, same problem Session is still not being assigned a Id. Also just checked the SQL Server to confirm that Id is marked as the PK, which is it.

Comment: I just noticed your id column type is `string`, which is why it cannot be auto-generated, maybe you want to use `int` or `Guid` instead? consider to use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` too.

Comment: Ahh that was it for that problem I changed to string in the first place so that I could work with Guid since I don't know anything about that Type yet. I think int will do for now. However I am now getting Exception saying that there is an entity that does not expose it's Foreign Key so that must be to do with my Measurements relationship

Comment: what's the exact exception message?

Comment: Oh, that's interesting, that Exception was saying as I descied but the the Inner Exception has this message ``InnerException {"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table dbo.Sessions'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."}`` Yet im looking at the Session being inserted and it clearly has a Id of 0

Comment: did you add `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`?

Comment: Wait, scratch the above, I know why the above isnt working, im not inserting the other entities in aswell, only setting them as attributes of Session, they need to be in their own table I think

Comment: Ok I am confused, fixed up my controller added in that attribute and still getting the above error

Comment: you need to add it in `Model` class, not in `Controller` :).

Comment: yeah I added it on the model, updated the database but I noticed that my Controller wasn't actually saving the measurements Objects to their respective tables

Comment: @kienct89 I finally found it, for some reason Identity doesen't like me using int as a PK so I changed back to Guid then made the controller generate a Guid, Thanks for your help